# On-premise Chatbot unable to receive msg from Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have set up the following network:
[chatbot setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w3qy.png)
Our internal chatbot is written in C#, and runs in .NET core linux env.
As of now, we are able to use the Bot Framework's Web Cmd to Send and Receive from our Internal Chatbot.   But we are unable to use MS Teams to communicate with our Internal Chat Bot.  We have set up App ID and App Password in the MS Team's App via App Studio.
We also enabled External App and Sideloading.

Is there any way to troubleshoot this? or is there something we may have missed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your request reaching API proxy?

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by "Bot Framework's Web Cmd"? Are you saying that the `Test in Web Chat` works, but using `Microsoft Teams` as a channel; it does not? Is your code based of a [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-samples), or is created using a visx/azure portal template? Do you have an exception or stack trace to show? Other than that, we need to know if it is hitting he proxy as Abhijit has asked.

Answer (score -1):

As per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), You need to also enable the Teams channel for your bot in the Azure Portal under Bot Management > Channels, for this to work.

Comment: Yes, we registered the bot in the Bot Framework Portal (https://dev.botframework.com/), and have enabled the MS Teams channel via the portal.